# How can I make my app look alike in both portrait and landscape view?

Tags: autolayout, swift2, ios9, xcode7.2, adaptive-layout

This is my constraint

[image: Constraints]

I have made use of auto layout in my app, all the UI elements are visible in portrait mode:

But the view is incomplete in landscape mode.

How can I make my app look alike in both portrait and landscape view?

I am using Swift 2 in Xcode7.2.

Comment: Could you also add the screenshot for portrait view?

Comment: Simulator Screen Shot Mar 9, 2016, 10.39.38 AM.png

Comment: edit the question and add the screenshot

Comment: Sir, I have added the screen shot, sorry for the delay incurred.

Comment: What are the constraints applied on 'login' and 'sign-up' buttons?

Comment: Login Constraints: aspect=165:31,    SIGN UP Constraints: height=29, width=165

Comment: I'll prefer to set `vertical space` between element instead of aspect

Answer (score 0):

use autolayout With Sizeclasses.
 [read this artical](http://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/auto-layout-intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

When handling screen with `UITextField` you should always use something scrollable, either a `UIScrollView` or a `UITableView`. By using, you can easily update your screen UI. I'm highly recommended not to use `UIScrollView`, `UITableView` will be more easy. And yes, there's one well maintained library (3rd party) https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding which will handle your tableview position when your textfield will get focus.

Comment: Sir I have  developed my app on swift, but the code of TPKeyboardAvoiding is in objective C. How can I make use of it? If it is impossible please suggest other alternatives

Comment: You can do this by doing bridging header to use objective-c classes in Swift. Here's a possible [solution](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/issues/157).